# Review problem for Calc 2 involving Polar Coordinates. Need an explanation of the steps highlighted in blue

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am familiar with the integration and how that works I just need an explanation of the highlighted steps and want to know how those steps make sense mathematically.

[image]

Comment: For the upper blue part: do you know how to find the solutions for $\tan(x)=1$ (in general)?

Comment: For the lower blue section, you seem to have lost a negative sign. You had $-\cos \frac{2\pi}8+\cos0$. The blue part should be $-\cos\frac\pi4+1$.

Comment: If $1 = \tan 2 \theta$, then $2 \theta = \arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$, so $\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$. The step you highlighted in blue drops a negative sign.